# AForge experience and file manipulation

Tags: c#, aforge

Morning all,

Does anyone on here have experience with using AForge and Video or webcam apps?

There is a .cs file called VideoCaptureDeviceForm that is part of AForge.DirectShow which provides a way of selecting a local video device i.e webcam.

I want to be able to automatically detect and start the webcam on my computer but a dialogbox pops up asking to select a webcam. I need a way to either bypass this in someway or automatically press the OK button.

[Dialogbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQKMf.jpg)

[image: App Error]

I have tried using SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") within the open dialogbox button method i.e Start camera but I get errors.

Within VideoCaptureDeviceForm.cs, there is a method called okButton_Click and the next idea is to manipulate this to do what I want the app to do.

Unfortunately I don't have the experience to figure this out. Can anyone advise on how to do this or what I should do next? Thank you.

VideoCaptureDeviceForm.cs is below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
    private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
    private Bitmap video;
    private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
    private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Start_Vid();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();

    }

    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (Stop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            //AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
            //AVIwriter.AddFrame(video);
        }
        else
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
    }

    private void Stop_Vid()
    {
        if (Stop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            Stop.Text = "Stop";
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            FileWriter.Close();
            //this.AVIwriter.Close();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }
    }
    private void butstop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Stop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            Stop.Text = "Stop";
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            FileWriter.Close();
            //this.AVIwriter.Close();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.Save("IMG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalVideo == null)
        { return; }
        if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            FileWriter.Close();
            //this.AVIwriter.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
        saveAvi.FileName = "New Vid1";

        if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
            int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
            FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.Default, 5000000);
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);


            //AVIwriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h);
            Stop.Text = "Stop Record";
            //FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            //FinalVideo.Start();
        }


    }

    //##############################################//
    //        Method not working        //
    //##############################################//

    private void Start_Vid()
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }
    }

    //##############################################//
    //        Method working            //
    //##############################################//

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }
    }
    private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please attach dialogue image.. and show your code where you call start webcam..please refine/minimum code so we can understand point problem..

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have added the dialogbox and replaced VideoCaptureDeviceForm.cs with my app code. I have included all but the problem is at private void Start_Vid(). I assumed that having SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); before the if statement it would work.

Comment: you need to select webcam first before starting.. I added the answer checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First, you need to find all webcam device is attached with you system

```
public FilterInfoCollection LoaclWebCamsCollection  = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

2) Then which webcam you want to use select "MonikerString" of that webcam

```
    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection["Select webcam you want to user"].MonikerString);
                      OR
    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection[0].MonikerString);




private void Start_Vid()
{
    FinalVideo = new 
    VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection[0].MonikerString);
    FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
    FinalVideo.Start();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, at what point in my app would I put this code? also will this automatically find the web cam and start it as I only have 1 webcam which is built into my laptop. The idea of my app is to be able progam when the webcam should turn on without user intervention to press OK.

Comment: Use this code in you start method just create VideoCaptureDevice  object and pass MonikerString of the webcam and then start

Comment: Ok so I have put the above code in Start_Vid() and ran it. The 2nd line gives the error "Non-invocable member 'VideoCaptureDevice' cannot be used like a method. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach the image with error? where you get the error? which version of aforge did you use? aforge  api's:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zdhlx2i1jsupqg/TinyTake27-08-2018-06-35-34.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have attached the error to my question. I am using AForge version 3.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

All code for VB.NET;
it needs a picturebox, a timer and a button,

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports AForge.Video.DirectShow

Public Class Form1
    Private videoSource As VideoCaptureDevice = Nothing
    Private videoSourcePlayer As AForge.Controls.VideoSourcePlayer = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim videoDevices As FilterInfoCollection = New FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)
        videoSource = New VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices.Item(0).MonikerString)
        videoSourcePlayer = New AForge.Controls.VideoSourcePlayer()
        videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = videoSource
        videoSourcePlayer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Stop playing
        videoSourcePlayer.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Timer1.Enabled Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim bitmap As Bitmap = videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrentVideoFrame()
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap
    End Sub
End Class
```